# How are Solr's stored and indexed fields stored internally (in Lucene)

Tags: solr, bigdata, search-engine, solr4

In Solr, when I set the field as 'indexed' but not 'stored', it is still stored in the index. If I go the other way around and set the field as 'stored' but not 'indexed', it is also stored in the index if I understand correctly.

My question is, how is the document stored internally in Lucene in these cases? How do 'stored' fields look like in Lucene and how do 'indexed' fields look like in Lucene internally.

The answer to this question will perhaps help me understand why atomic updates in Solr only work with stored fields and not indexed fields (as explained here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Atomic_Updates#Stored_Values).

Answer (score 4):

In Solr/Lucene, **indexed** and **stored** are two different concepts.

**indexed** means the field value will be saved in inverted index, and you can search on them when you do query.  But you can't see them in search results documents.

**stored** just means it will be saved in stored field value part, not in inverted index, which means it cannot be searched, but can be used to display when you get search results documents.

Actually, the way how Solr do update is, it will take out the whole document(only stored fields), change the value you want to update, and save them back(with re-index).  That's why it can only support stored fields.

Comment: To further expand on this, consider the value "value this value is value a value" in a field. The index will just have references from "this", "is", "a" and "value" to the internal docId. It's impossible recreate the original value from that (this is a simpliciation, there will be other values attached to the token other than just the docId, such as frequency ("termFreq")). See https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene53/package-summary.html#package_description for the Lucene documentation)

Comment: Thanks Zhitao! :) You said 'stored just means it will be saved in doc value part, not in inverted index'. Can you please tell me more about this 'doc value part' - maybe some documentation you can point to please?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up stored field value and document value.  They are different.  Stored field value is only for return your origin field value, since sometimes the origin value is different with index value, such as after going through tokenizer.  Same with what Mats said.  Doc value is another thing, also keyed by document number, but used for faceting or other functions.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/DocValues

Comment: To further further expand on this: Solr can not update single fields like an sql database. "Internally Solr re-adds the full document to the index with the updated fields."

Comment: Thanks @ZhitaoYue . Can you please tell me then where are the fields which are 'stored' but not 'indexed' actually stored? If they are not stored in the 'inverted index' then where are they stored?

Comment: If you open your solr data directory, and navigate to [core]/data/index folder, you can find some `.fdt` files which are where stored field value are stored.  And inverted index are mainly stored in `.tim` files.